# DLL load failed while importing _imaging:

Tags: python, matplotlib, dll, cmd, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to run my Python program and these are the modules I'm importing:

> from tkinter import *
> from functools import partial
> import numpy as np   import
> matplotlib   matplotlib.use("TkAgg")
> from matplotlib.figure import Figure
> from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg
> import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk

I always end up with the following error message:

```
C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py:138: UserWarning: mkl-service package failed to import, therefore Intel(R) MKL initialization ensuring its correct out-of-the box operation under condition when Gnu OpenMP had already been loaded by Python process is not assured. Please install mkl-service package, see http://github.com/IntelPython/mkl-service
  from . import _distributor_init
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ASRS.py", line 12, in <module>
    from matplotlib.figure import Figure
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 18, in <module>
    from matplotlib import docstring, projections
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\projections\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .. import axes, docstring
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._subplots import *
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 6, in <module>
    from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 14, in <module>
    import matplotlib.contour as mcontour
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\contour.py", line 17, in <module>
    import matplotlib.text as text
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .textpath import TextPath  # Unused, but imported by others.
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\textpath.py", line 11, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\mathtext.py", line 27, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
  File "C:\Users\HP\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 94, in <module>
    from . import _imaging as core
**ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _imaging: Belirtilen modül bulunamadı.**
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe you should: `python -m pip install --force-reinstall Pillow`.

Answer (score 21):

Simply upgrading the package "Pillow" worked for me to resolve this issue. Hence, either

```
pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

or

```
conda update Pillow
```

should do the trick (depending on your environment).

Comment: Are you expressly `pip install`ing, as opposed to `conda install`ing (which would seem more appropriate in an Anaconda environment), because you need to, in order to fix the problem? That is, does: `conda install --upgrade Pillow` _not_ fix the problem?

Comment: You're right. I just edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Which versions are affected? When was this bug fixed in the source code?

Answer (score 2):

your python version is "3.8". use one of following version of pillow:

- 6.2.1
- 7.0
- 8.0
- 8.3.2
- 9.0
- 9.3

I don't know why but this solution worked for me.

Comment: using pillow 9.3 worked for me. version 9.5 didn't work.

Comment: What is your list of versions based on?

Comment: dear @xjcl, I got this list by trial and error. Some time ago, I had a problem with the installation of the pillow. I did not get a good result by searching the internet. So I started to install different versions of pillow while my Python version was 3.8. It turned out that (at least for me) this list of versions of pillow works with Python 3.8 and does not cause the error in question.

Answer (score 1):

Note: uninstalling pillow might remove other packages, so in my opinion try this first. It might be the case that you actually don't need to use the pillow module, so instead only import the modules you need i.e: from some_package import function_one, function_two, etc...