# DLL load failed while importing _imaging

Tags: matplotlib, tkinter, cmd, anaconda, exe

it's a newbie question here because this is the first time I want to create an .exe from a python script. I get the error message in the title and can't fix it... **work with Anaconda cmd, but not the regular cmd**. i found similar issue on the web but the answers they proposed did not work to me, could someone kindly tell me what's happening and how to avoid it? Find below the detail of the errors.

**also i give to you the modules i use:**

```
import tkinter as tk 
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import (FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk)
import re
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import statistics
```

the program creates a graph in a small interface from datas collected by a machine in a txt file

```
C:\Users\c.maujean>C:\Users\c.maujean\dist\to_TEST\to_TEST.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):


File "c.maujean\to_TEST.py", line 157, in <module>
  File "c.maujean\to_TEST.py", line 9, in main
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib\__init__.py", line 107, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib\rcsetup.py", line 24, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "matplotlib\animation.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 499, in exec_module
  File "PIL\Image.py", line 114, in <module>
ImportError: **DLL load failed while importing _imaging**: The specified module could not be found.


[20640] Failed to execute script 'to_TEST' due to unhandled exception!
```

Thank you so much for your kind help !

Comment: Maybe you can try with this workarounds: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66385979/dll-load-failed-while-importing-imaging or https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/11103